# Sencha touch 2 how to load a model without using store?

Tags: extjs, model, proxy, sencha-touch-2, store

Is there any convenient way to load a single model with proxy set in sencha touch 2.X? Normally I would use a store, but in this situation I only want to load a single instance and my proxy always returns only one instance. In this situation the use of a store seems to be somewhat "useless" because it always tries to load multiple instances when using `store.load()`.